# what make insert into select sql statement very slowly(no resultset return)

Tags: sql, oracle

execute very slowly on below sql statement, env: oracle 9. Please advise the cause or hints to debug. Thanks a lot .

```
INSERT INTO tmp_table (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9)
select * from my_view where col1 = 1;
```

How far i tested: execute the select sub-statement cost 3 sec to get 1 record returned while endless executing but no resultset returned when execute the entire statement, like hanging.

Comment: How many columns match your select ?

Comment: 9 columns in both tmp_table and my_view.

Comment: Have u tried using APPEND ?

Comment: What is the definition of the view `my_view`?  What does an explain plan or trace show?

Comment: You should name your fields in the select clause, instead of using *. If you add a field to my_view, your sentence will fail, and it's much better for (our) understanding.

Comment: @eternay,thanks and i know, will affect speed or not?

Comment: @Prix, may i have more details on APPEND?

Comment: @Tony Andrews,and i got solution ,it appears to solved the issue, use below   `select /*+ no_merge(my_view) use_hash(my_view) */` why who knows

Comment: @user622851 try running `EXPLAIN PLAN`

Comment: @all, i got you guys, you suspected the view is slow, but i already said **execute the select sub-statement cost 3 sec(got 1 record)**, so i cant understand, anyway, will look into `the explain plan`

Answer (score 0):

When a query appears to execute quickly, in the sense that the last row is returned quickly rather than just the first row, but it runs slowly when used in an insert statement, the usual suspects are:

1. A change in the execution plan, driven by the optimiser believing that an all_rows goal is now appropriate where previously a first_rows goal was used. Check the execution plan for changes.
2. Some action being executed as a result of the insert. Slow triggers on the target table, or materialised view logging, are possible causes. This would not be the case when running "create table ... as select ..".